# Struts2 Rest plugin unable to load configuration bean

Tags: java, rest, plugins, struts2

I am trying out the struts2 Rest plugin, upon adding the jar to my lib folder this error showed up.

```
Jan 18, 2013 9:16:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/John/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/HitPlay/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-rest-plugin-2.3.7.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:36:138
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:483)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5306)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/John/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/HitPlay/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-rest-plugin-2.3.7.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:36:138
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:71)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:429)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:471)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: Unable to load bean: type:org.apache.struts2.rest.handler.ContentTypeHandler class:org.apache.struts2.rest.handler.JsonLibHandler - bean - jar:file:/C:/Users/John/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/HitPlay/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-rest-plugin-2.3.7.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:36:138
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:245)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.register(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:102)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:215)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:68)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/json/JSONArray
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:235)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.JSONArray
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    ... 25 more
```

I have no idea why this is happening.  any clues?

Comment: You're missing required libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing required libraries, at least the JSON library. This may be because you're not using Maven or an equivalent.

You can't just drop a plugin library into your app and expect  it to work, plugins have their own dependencies.